# line break in regular expressions in php

Tags: php, expression, row, line, break

I was developing a search system in PHP without using MySQL. So I created a system that looks for words in php files. It works fine, but the problem is displaying the pages found. I am trying to use a regular expression to show the title of the page (if exists) on the found pages, like this:

```
preg_match_all('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/',$conteudo,  $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

It works fine when there are no line breaks after the title tag. but if I break the line after the  tag for example, it doesn't work. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

add the `s (PCRE_DOTALL)` flag to your regex (ie. append `s` after the ending `/`) , so the `.` in the regex will match newlines.

```
s (PCRE_DOTALL)
If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. 
This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. 
A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.
```

Comment: sorry, I am not very used to regular expressions, can you show how the code should be? Thanks

Comment: you really should read the preg_match_all *documentation* of flags. They are really easy to use, and e. g.  ignore case is essential.

Comment: add 's' at the end of the regex: `preg_match_all('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/s', $conteudo` ...

Comment: I don't have php here, but according to online tester: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/9cB it works